# How to refresh a page or div with jquery in order to reveal new data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've got some jquery that submits a form for me. It works just fine. The only major problem is how simple it is.

The form submits the info to the database using my php script without refreshing the page, but the page isn't updated in any way to show the new data. What are some good ways to update the page or div so my new data is displayed after submitting the form. Below is my code

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        // Stop the form actually posting
        e.preventDefault();

        // Send the request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $('textarea#joke').val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: $('textarea#joke').html(html);just use it

Comment: what does the `submit.php` file returns? on success

Comment: On success, nothing right now. It just returns on failure. What would I do different once I set it up to return something upon success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, just use html() method or text() depend on your needs, for your example I think text is better, since you want put text into textarea

```
success: function(html){
                $('textarea#joke').text(html);
            }
```

but if you want put some html into custom div do

```
success: function(html){
                    $('#custom-div').html(html);
                }
```

Comment: Under my form I have a div with the database content displayed inside. I'm just wanting to refresh it to display the new data. The second example you posted works, but what is the difference in it and
`$("#joke-wrap").prepend(html);`?

Comment: Prepend method will add more text next to <div id="joke-wrap"> each time you use it, html method will overwrite everything inside div to new html. For example with prepend method you will get something like `<div id="joke-wrap"><p>just prepended</p><p>just prepended</p><p>just prepended</p></div>` with html you will get `<div id="joke-wrap"><p>just prepended</p></div>` only.

Comment: I don't know if your comment got cut off or what. Which is a better method to load new content? .prepend or .html?

Comment: I just finish my comment. ^_^

Comment: Oh, so .prepend just calls what is new then right? Where as .html reloads it all at once?

Comment: Prepend will add more data into your div each time, for example if your div contain something like `<div id="joke-wrap"><p>allready here</p></div>` prepend will add more data in beginning `<div id="joke-wrap"><p>new html</p><p>allready here</p></div>` with html all data will be overwrited `<div id="joke-wrap"><p>new html</p></div>`.

Comment: Thanks! .prepend is just what i needed! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose from the submit.php, you are returning some value as `status = true` if form submitted suceessfully else `status = false`

then in your ajax code, you can use it as

```
success: function(html){
  if(html.status == true)
    $('textarea#joke').html('Form submitted succcessfully');
  else
    $('textarea#joke').html('ERROR!');
}
```

OR

```
success: function(html){
    $('textarea#joke').val(html.status);
}
```

This would update the div content of `$('textarea#joke')`

Hope this would help you.

Thanks.